# Lightweight Youtube embed + G. Analytics event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube

I am using the following code to embed the videos from Youtube:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qcr60xz/

It does not load the video when the page loads but only when the user requests them (by clicking the "fake player").

I would like to set up a Google Analytics event tracking for when users to click on "fake player" that renders the true iframe video.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
```

Is there a way to do it with this jsFiddle code?

**Thank you, guys!**

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".youtube-player").addEventListener("click",function(){
  ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
});
```

`document.querySelector` selects the element on the page (your fake player), we then add an event listener to that element, with the `addEventListener` function.

Comment: Thanks, @Mathijs! :-)